# Replace XML attribute value

Tags: xml, vbscript, nodes, xmlnode

I've been reading about working with XML files for the past couple days and am pulling my hair out.

It seems like it would be simple to get an attribute and change the value but I can't make it happen.

I have the following XML file called input.xml:

```
<gs:GlobalizationService xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
    <gs:UserList>
        <gs:User UserID="Current"/>
    </gs:UserList>
    <gs:InputPreferences>
        <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0409:00000409" Default="true"/>
    </gs:InputPreferences>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

I need to be able to change the value of the attribute ID.  It seems as though I should be able to use a combination of the selectSingleNode and setAttribute commands to accomplish this but I can't get it to work.

A snippet of what I have been trying follows.  Value is defined elsewhere in the main script based on a user selection.

```
Dim xmlDoc, xmlNode
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmldoc.Load("input.xml")

Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("gs:GlobalizationServices/gs:InputPreferences/gs:InputLanguageID")
xmlNode.setAttribute "ID", Value
xmlDoc.save("input.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using a XPath selector and then compile the selector.  I don't think you need to use any 3rd party libraries.  I think JDK has the stuff you need to do it.  There are examples if you Google it.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use a skeleton with basic error checking like

```
Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("...")
Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
oXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
' If namespace(s)
' oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "...'"
oXML.async = False
oXML.load sFSpec
If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
   WScript.Echo oXML.xml
   WScript.Echo "-----------------"
   Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "..."
   Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = oXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
   If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
      WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
   Else
      WScript.Echo ndFnd.nodeName, ndFnd.getAttribute("UserID")
      WScript.Echo "-----------------"
      ndFnd.setAttribute "UserID", "Changed"
      WScript.Echo oXML.xml
      oXML.save Replace(sFSpec, ".xml", "-o.xml")
   End If
Else
   WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

(2) After filling in the file spec, you realize that your XML is not wellformed.

```
script 13589885.vbs
nd tag 'gs:GlobalizationServices' does not match the start tag 'gs:GlobalizationService'.
```

(3) As the XML contains (a) namespace(s), you need

```
oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:gs='urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend'"
...
Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/gs:GlobalizationService/gs:UserList/gs:User"
```

(4) And now it does not obviously break down:

```
cscript 13589885.vbs
<gs:GlobalizationService xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
        <gs:UserList>
                <gs:User UserID="Current"/>
        </gs:UserList>
        <gs:InputPreferences>
                <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0409:00000409" Default="true"/>
        </gs:InputPreferences>
</gs:GlobalizationService>

-----------------
gs:User Current
-----------------
<gs:GlobalizationService xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
        <gs:UserList>
                <gs:User UserID="Changed"/>
        </gs:UserList>
        <gs:InputPreferences>
                <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0409:00000409" Default="true"/>
        </gs:InputPreferences>
</gs:GlobalizationService>
```

(5) Reflect upon why `xmldoc.Load("input.xml")` and `xmlDoc.save("input.xml")` are bad VBScript.